# What is alternative to Unity's lens for Gnome Shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, lenses

Is there any functionality like lens for Gnome shell? or any modified version of Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 2):

I was very happy with `gnome-do`, but with Ubuntu Quantal I've got some problems with the hotkeys: I had to set the activation hotkey on every new session and it was everyday.

In 2 days I was looking for a solution and found more than that: [Meet Synapse – the super fast new GNOME Do replacement](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu)

To install it, just the commands above:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Talking about the plugin usage, that @Evandro Silva mentioned, it's possible with Sypase too.

P.S.: You can found more information and some snapshots in the website that I mentioned. I took the commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

I use `gnome-do`, just search for it on the software center, or use the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

Like unity lens, you can add plugins to search for more specific things:

[image]